# No method named samethod() on view.main.MainController

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am getting error `No method samethod() named on view.main.MainController`
I am using controller from view method only not from view.main

I have function `samethod()` in `view.sa.sacontroller` not in `view.main.MainController`.

I do not know why it is pointing to another location.

I have another button for that all is working good and referring to  `view.sa.sacontroller` 
I created new window and in that  one button click event is referring `view.main.MainController` to this location

`Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {`

Can you please help me ?

**Code:-**

```
click: function () {
    var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        items: {
            xtype: 'form',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Cancel',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                    this.up('window').hide();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Click',
                handler: 'clickevent()'
            }]
        }
    });
}
```

`clickevent()` function is in another file controller

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: added code Please check

Answer (score 1):

Once window is created it will not inherit the controller of the parent in which it is created. For the controller of newly created window should point to controller class where you expect your method to be present.

> controller: 'view.sa.sacontroller'

This should be added inside the ext create of the window.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: controller.view.sa.sacontroller' giving me this error

Comment: Extjs is not able to recognize the class. So, add "requires" config pointing to the full path of the controller class.